# Passing json array of array in django to javascript google charts

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-visualization

I have an actuals array of array coming from django queryset as a json. I am having trouble feeding it to the google charts.js
Below is the code.
views.py

```
def historicals(request):
    actuals= serializers.serialize("json",Del.objects.all()[1:10])
    json_object = json.loads(actuals)
    actuals=[]
    i=1
    for element in json_object:
       dt=element['fields']['Date']
       dt=datetime.datetime.strptime(dt,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
       dt=dt.date()
       dt=datetime.datetime.strftime(dt,'%Y-%m-%d')
       Vol=str(element['fields']['Volume'])
       print (dt)
       cn=str(element['fields']['Customer'])
       cn = str(cn)     
       actuals.append([pxn,Vol,dt])
        
    print (actuals)
    context['actuals']=actuals
  
    return render(request,'customer.html',context)
```

```
var actuals = "{{ actuals | safe }}";
```

will shows the following in page source.

```
[['001', '5155', '2020-01-14'], ['001', '57.0', '2020-02-13'], ['001', '510', '2020-02-25'], ['001', '5760', '2020-03-23'], ['001', '46.625', '2020-03-30'], ['001', '910', '2020-04-01'], ['001', '435300.0', '2020-03-20']]
```

```
console.log(actuals); //Would show the above array of arrays
for (i = 0; i < actuals.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < actuals[i].length; j++) {
    var dt = i;
    actual = actuals[i][j]; //tried parseFloat too didnt work 
    //data.addRow([i,actual[i][1]);
    console.log(actuals[i][j]); //--> this shows individual characters in the array [ , 0 0 0 0 1
  }
}
```

I am trying to iteratively add a row using the `data.addRow` line. My problem is `actuals[i][j]` is showing an individual character (this shows individual characters in the array [ , 0 0 0 0 1....) in console.log  instead of whole string or numbers or dates.

I was expecting the `console.log(actuals[i][j])` to show
`['001', '5155', '2020-01-14']` in the browser console. Can you help?

Comment: please show the expected result for the set of data you show `[['001', '5155', '2020-01-14'], ['001', '57.0', '2020-02-13'], ['001', '510', '2020-02-25'], ['001', '5760', '2020-03-23'], ['001', '46.625', '2020-03-30'], ['001', '910', '2020-04-01'], ['001', '435300.0', '2020-03-20']]`

Comment: in this line `actual = actuals([i][j]);` you get `TypeError: actuals is not a function` try instead `actual = actuals[i][j];` without parentheses

Comment: It's probably easier/safer to use [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) to pass context variables to your JS

Answer (score 1):

`actuals[i][j]` should show only one value.

If what you need is to pass each instance of the array as an argument to data.addRow you can use forEach, for example

```
actuals.forEach((entry, index) => data.addRow(index, entry));
```

If you need to transform the array data before using it in `data.addRow()` you can do the following

```
actuals.forEach((entry, index) => {
  const item = [+entry[0], +entry[1], new Date(entry[2])];

  data.addRow(index, item);
});
```

The unary + operator will convert the string to number

Answer (score 0):

In the context variable, I removed the quotes and the loop and charts worked very easily after that.

```
var actuals = {{ actuals | safe }};
```